# How to search for a specific string in files from a specific date?

Tags: linux, grep, find, date

How can I search for a specific string in files from a specific date?

For example, I have 3 files named

```
'a1' dated: 20 Feb,
'a2' dated 21 Feb,
'a3' dated 22 Feb.
```

Now I want to search for a certain string like 'JMS111' in all files where date = '21 Feb'.

I tried below commands but wasn't successful:

```
ls -lt |grep 'JMS111' -ctime 2019/02/21 
find -name '*.xml' -type f -printf '%Tw:%h/%f\0' | grep 'JMS111'
```

Comment: note that putty is just your interface to some other system (presumably Linux, given the tag); I'll remove the putty tag since your question is more directly about find & grep

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

One way to approach this is to set up timestamp files to bracket the dates you're looking for:

```
touch -t 201902210000 /tmp/start-time
touch -t 201902212359.59 /tmp/end-time
```

... and then ask `find` for files that are newer than the start-time but *not* newer than the end-time:

```
find . -type f  -newer /tmp/start-time  ! -newer /tmp/end-time
```

Putting it all together:

```
touch -t 201902210000 /tmp/start-time
touch -t 201902212359.59 /tmp/end-time
find . -type f -newer /tmp/start-time  ! -newer /tmp/end-time -name '*.xml' -exec grep JMS111 /dev/null {} +
rm /tmp/start-time /tmp/end-time
```

This will look for files in the right timeframe with names ending in `.xml` and then
pass those filenames to the `grep`, fitting in as many as it can per pass. I've added `/dev/null` as a "file" for grep to search from along with the filenames from `find`, if any. That way, if there is only one matching file, `grep` is "forced" to report the matching filename (as /dev/null will never match, it won't be reported).

Your output will be the filenames and matching lines from those files.

Comment: ... or with GNU `find`, you could use date strings directly I think e.g. `-newermt '21 Feb' ! -newermt '22 Feb'`

Comment: I recommend `grep -H`, in case there's only one matching file.  Or, more portably, add `/dev/null` to the `grep` command to ensure there's always at least two.

Comment: Thanks, Toby! I've incorporated the `/dev/null` suggestion as a more-general solution.  Feel free to edit in such excellent suggestions directly next time!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`find . -name 'a[123]' -ctime 6 | xargs grep -l 'JMS111'`

The `-ctime 6` looks for any file that's 6 days old. It actually compares the creation date of the file to the 24 hour period that's between 6*24 hours an 7*24 hours prior to your running the command. If the creation date is in that period, and the filename is 'a1', 'a2', or 'a3', then `find` prints the path of that file. Since the period specified by -ctime <n> is based on when you ran the find command, you will have to use a different value for <n> if you run find tomorrow, than if you run it today.

Note: If you use `-ctime -6`, find will print filenames that are 6 or fewer days old, `-ctime +6` will print file names that are 6 days or older. Also, some versions of find will allow you to specify units of measurement, e.g 6h, for 6 hours old.

You could instead use `-mtime` if you want to search on modification time instead of creation time.

Using `xargs` makes it easy to check if you are getting the correct list of file from find before doing the `grep`. Also, if you put grep in a `-exec` primary, find invokes it once for each file it finds, whereas, `xargs` receives a list of files that it passes to a single invocation of `grep`, which is less resource intensive.

One disadvantage of `-ctime` is you have to calculate the number of days since the file was created, but you can figure that out by running

```
find . -ctime n | xargs ls -l
```

until you see files with the date you're interested in.

... And, you don't have to remember to delete the bracketing files like you do with `-newer`.

Comment: consider directly calling `-exec grep` so that you don't break when filenames contain special characters (spaces, newlines)

Comment: If files contain spaces (or new-lines) you can change the command to `find . -name 'a[123]' -ctime 6 | sed -e "s/.*/'&'" | xargs grep -l 'JMS111'` and the filenames will be passed to grep in tact.

Comment: Just a warning that most filesystems don't store a *creation* date - `-ctime` works on the last *inode changed* time, which will be updated e.g. when permission bits are changed.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the below screenshot,

[image]

We need to list a file that contains a particular string and which is created on a particular date. We can execute the below command for this,

- **sudo find . -type f -newermt 2020-10-06 -exec grep -l "test" {} \;**

The above command will list the files created on Oct 6 and which contain the string 'test'. Refer to the below screenshot,

[image]

In the first screenshot, you can see 3 files. Two of them (test.scala and text2.txt) contain a string 'test' but their creation date is different. And in the second screenshot, you can see that we listed the file that contains the string 'test' and which is created on Oct 6.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note posting [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) is discouraged as they are often difficult to read. Instead, copy-and-paste the content as text, using proper formatting.

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

```
$ grep -e JMS111 *20190221*.txt
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer assumes that the file's date is encoded in its file *name*, which the question does not specify.